# Adding GUID parameter to a sql string

Tags: t-sql

I am having complications adding a guid type to a sql string and getting the query to go. I have to write the sql this because I need to pass the name database as a parameter.

The following code is what I'm trying to do but it doesnt work. No matter what I do it doesn't read the GUID correctly. It gives me the following error when executing the stored proc. Probably because guid has "-" in them

> Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Here's the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[templatesAndBaskets_Select]
 @guid uniqueidentifier,
 @DatabaseName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @sql varchar(max)

Set @sql=

'select soldtoid 
from '    +  @DatabaseName + '.templatesAndBaskets' +
' where ordergroupid = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(max),@guid)

print @sql
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
END
```

Comment: @Aaron I updated the question. The stored proc complies but it doesnt work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably just simply need to put single quotes around the GUID :

```
SET @sql =
   N'SELECT soldtoid FROM ' +  @DatabaseName + N'.templatesAndBaskets' +
   N' WHERE ordergroupid = ''' +  CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @guid) + N''''
```

That should result in a SQL statement something like this:

```
SELECT soldtoid FROM database.templatesAndBaskets
WHERE ordergroupid = '5E736CE7-5527-40ED-8499-2CA93FC7BC9C'
```

which is valid - yours without the single quotes around the GUID isn't valid...

**Update:** you also need to change your `@sql` variable to `NVARCHAR` for `sp_Executesql` - try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[templatesAndBaskets_Select]
    @guid uniqueidentifier,
    @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @sql =
       N'SELECT soldtoid FROM ' +  @DatabaseName + N'.templatesAndBaskets' +
       N' WHERE ordergroupid = ''' +  CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @guid) + N''''

   PRINT @sql
   EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @sql
END
```

Does that work??

Comment: I tried running this but am still getting the same error Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: @NickLaMarca: and you're **200% sure** that you've used my adapted code with the extra single quotes around the GUID ?? What do you get from your `PRINT` statement?? Can you show us that??

Comment: I changed the quid param to a varchar and get this:

Comment: select soldtoid 
from pm.templatesAndBaskets where ordergroupid = 'B28960DC-607D-4857-8638-00011B665B22'
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 0):

Put the @guid between '

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[templatesAndBaskets_Select]
 @guid uniqueidentifier,
 @DatabaseName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @sql varchar(max)

Set @sql=

"select soldtoid from "    +  @DatabaseName + ".templatesAndBaskets" +
" where ordergroupid = '" +  CONVERT(varchar(max),@guid)+"'"

print @sql
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
END
```